# Mongoid, calling update_attributes twice to persist change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following models:

```
class Group
  ...
  has_many :users, dependent: :delete
  ...
end

class User
  belongs_to :group
  has_one :invitation, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'to_id'

  validates_presence_of :group
end

class Invitation
  belongs_to :to, class_name: "User"

  validates :to, presence: true
end
```

If I create a new `group = Group.create!(name: 'foo')`, `group.persisted? => true` and then update a user's group `user.update_attributes!(group: group)`:

```
MONGODB (1.4ms) db['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB (13.7ms) db['invitations'].find({"to_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (204.4ms) db['users'].find({:deleted_at=>nil, "user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (1.0ms) db['groups'].find({:deleted_at=>nil, :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('516db306627b164bdb000012'), :_type=>{"$in"=>["Account"]}}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (183.2ms) db['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"users", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, :slug=>"7d3a-jonathan-grin", :_id=>{"$ne"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.2ms) db['users'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}, {"$set"=>{"slug"=>"7d3a-jonathan-grin", "updated_at"=>2013-05-02 20:54:42 UTC}})
=> true
```

As you can see in the last sentence of Mongoid log (`update` method), the group is not being set.

If I run `user.update_attributes!(group: group)` once again:

```
MONGODB (132.9ms) db['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"users", "query"=>{:deleted_at=>nil, :slug=>"1e30-jonathan-grin", :_id=>{"$ne"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.1ms) db['users'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5170657d627b165f33000002')}, {"$set"=>{"group_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5182d256218c5a0c8a000004'), "slug"=>"1e30-jonathan-grin", "updated_at"=>2013-05-02 20:56:34 UTC}})
=> true
```

I get only two queries and the **group is updated**.

Same occurs with `group.users << user`.

- All callbacks are commented.
- I'm testing it in rails console.
- MongogoDB version 2.2.3
- Mongoid version 2.6.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

which safety level are you using?

Depending on how you configure it, Mongoid might be reporting a change as persisted when it is in fact only recorded in memory on the MongoDB server - not yet persisted to disk

Try something like this:

```
 Group.with(safe: {w:2,fsync:true}).create!  # requires Mongoid 3.x
```

or

```
 Group.safely(w:2, fsync: true).create!   # requires Mongoid 2.x
```

You can also set a default safety level in the `config/mongoid.yml` file of your Rails project.

See also:

- http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html
- http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration
- http://two.mongoid.org/docs/persistence/safe_mode.html (Mongoid 2.x)

The values that can be passed with :safe are:

- true: Persist in safe mode, no extra options.
- false: Don't persist in safe mode.
- fsync: true|false: Whether to perform an fsync.
- w: n: The number of nodes to write to before returning.
- wtimeout: n: The timeout value for writing to multiple nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I got: `NoMethodError: undefined method `with' for Group:Class`

Comment: I'm using a very basic mongoid.yml... host, db and `use_object_ids: true`

Comment: I try `Group.safely({w:2,fsync:true}).create!(name: 'foo')` => `Mongo::OperationFailure: : norepl`

Comment: which Mongoid version are you using?? 3.x or 2.x ?

Comment: MongogoDB version 2.2.3 and Mongoid version 2.6.0

Comment: then check out the last link I just added to the post